# Conversion from GB to DWORD or vice-versa

Tags: c, dword

I want to compare a filesize to check if it is below 8GB. How could I convert either the filseSize( which is in DWORD)  to GB or the 8 GB to DWORD?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean convert "bytes" to "gigabytes"? There are 2^30 bytes in a gb. So 8GB = 2^30 * 8 = 8,589,934,592 B.

Comment: Badly written question.  Read this: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I've given you an answer that I think works for you.  But it's a shot in the dark guess given the limited information you provided.  Consider re-writing your question.

Comment: What Windows API are you calling to get file size?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing from your `DWORD` hint, you are on the Windows platform and using Win32 APIs to get file sizes.

Don't call [GetFileSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesize).  It's limited to a DWORD (32-bit), which I think it what your question is about.

Instead, invoke [GetFileSizeEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex), which gives you back a 64-bit result for a file handle.  Or [GetFileAttributesEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) which gives back a struct with a 64-bit size in it split across two dwords.

Example:

```
const LONGLONG MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024LL * 1024LL * 1024LL * 8;
LARGE_INTEGER li = {0};
if (GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &li)) {
    LONGLONG filesize = li.QuadPart;
    if (filesize > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        ...
    }
}
```

OR

```
const LONGLONG MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024LL * 1024LL * 1024LL * 8;
WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA info = {0};
if (GetFileAttributesEx(filename, GetFileExInfoStandard, (void*)&info)) {
    LONGLONG filesize = info.nFileSizeHigh;
    filesize  = filesize << 32;
    filesize |= info.nFileSizeLow;
    if (filesize > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Excellent decyphering of the question :) (And excellent answer)